# Upper before Concat in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, string-concatenation, uppercase

Assuming there is a table called cities with columns name and country, why doesn't this query work?

```
select
  concat(upper(name, ', ', country)) as location
FROM
  cities;
```

But the one below does?

```
select
  upper(concat(name, ', ', country)) as location
FROM
  cities;
```

I tried both approaches, but couldn't figure out why the first did not work, but the second did.

Now if there are two or more operations, how do I decide on their ordering so the query works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres' [`UPPER()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function is defined to accept a single string input, not a CSV list of several strings as input.  Apparently, your first query is working without uppercasing, but there is not any guarantee that Postgres should even accept that syntax.

The second version is the correct one, where you concatenate first, then passed that concatenated string as a single input into the `UPPER()` function.

Answer (score 1):

UPPER function only accepts a single string parameter. [reference](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/upper-function.php)
In the first query, you are passing multiple params, so that causes error.
In your second query, you concat multiple params into a single string then pass it to UPPER, so it works.